# How to find the decomposition into disjoint cycles?

Tags: combinatorics

Please explain how to go about solving these problems. I put my answers below each one but I don't think I did it correctly.

$1. (1 2)(1 3 4 2)(4 3 5)(2 5)$

**Answer:** $(5 2 3 1 4)$

$2. (1 2 3)^{-1}(1 4 5 3 6)(1 2 3)$

**Answer:** $(4 2 6 5 3 1)$

Comment: For the first, note that $(1~2)(1~3~4~2)(4~3~5)(2~5) = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5\\ 3&1&5&4&2\end{pmatrix}$.  Check that you understand why.  Now that we have it in a two-line format, can you see what the disjoint cycles are that make it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general algorith for every such composition of cycles. Pick a random number that hasn't been written already (at the beginning no number is chosen, so we are free to choose any, i.e. 1). Then starting from right to left we have that first two cycles fix $1$, while the third send $1$ to $3$. The last cycle fixes $3$. Hence we can write $(13..)$. Now repeat the same thing for $3$ and we'll get that $3$ is sent to $5$, hence we add $5$ in the cycle and we get $(135..)$. We continue in this manner until we get the first number in this case $1$ and then we close the brace. Now repeat this algorithm until all numbers are exhausted to get the final answer.

For the first case the answer should be $(1352)(4)$, which is equal to $(1352)$. Can you find the answer of the second one on your own?

Note that to get the inverse all you need is to reverse the order of the element, i.e. $(123)^{-1} = (321)$